# Date.parse is not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I have to parse two dates for example start date and end date.

```
var startdate = '30-04-2014 05:30:00 PM';
var enddate = '02-05-2014 05:52:36 PM';
```

But if we alert start date

```
alert(Date.Parse(startdate));
```

I will get 1465041600000

but if I alert `enddate`

```
alert(Date.Parse(enddate));
```

I will get 1391602956000

But this is not working properly, because the `enddate` is larger than `startdate`, but after parsing we will get larger value for start date. I want to get the difference between these 2 days.
Can anybody know a workaround for this?

Comment: This is just javascript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date.parse('30-04-2014 05:30:00 PM') // returns NAN!
```

I Assume you mean 30th April 2014 and 2nd May 2014 in which case it should be (mm-dd-yyyy)

```
Date.parse('04-30-2014 05:30:00 PM') // returns 1398844800000
```

and

```
Date.parse('05-02-2014 05:30:00 PM') // returns 1399018956000
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and time) can be passed and parsed.

So:

**ISO 8601 format:** yyyy-mm-dd

**Your format:** dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

var date = new Date(); initialized date from the current time

date.setDate(arrival.getDate()+nights); sets the day of month in date to the day of month in arrival and added +nights.

If today is in May, date is in May, and if arrival is in June, the 2nd line does not set the month in date to June.

Try this:

```
var arrival = parseDate($('#arrivaldate').val());
var depart = new Date(arrival);
var nights = parseInt($('#nights').val());
depart.setDate(arrival.getDate()+nights);
console.log(depart);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in java script itself, try following code

```
    var x = new Date('your start goes here');
    var y = new Date('your end date goes here');
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(y.getTime() - x.getTime());
    var days = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

The variable days has diff b/w two days

Answer (score 0):

I think your Strings are wrong. 02-05-2014 is February the 5th, and 30-04-2014 does not exist.

But there is the Date "04-30-2014" which is April the 30th.

I think that is your problem.